# Spring Model Attribute Binding Issue with Square Brackets

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jackson-databind

- **Spring MVC Version**: 4.3.25
- **Spring Boot**: 1.5.22 (Stuck to this due an old webshpere server version :( compatible only with JEE6)
- **Jackson Data-Bind**: 2.10.3

My UI form submits POST request with parameters sent (inspected through browser tools).

*Content-Type on Http Request is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"*

```
changedValues[contacts[0]]  12312312313 
changedValues[contacts[1]]  345354535 
changedValues[contacts[2]]  35534534 
name Sam
```

My Spring MVC controller goes like this.
**Controller Code**

```
@PostMapping("/saveMyPage")
public String saveMyPage(Model model,HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        HttpSession session,@ModelAttribute("myBean") MyBean oBean,BindingResult result){

    Map <String,Object> uiChanged = oBean.changedValues;
   ... Other Code

 }
```

**Bean Code**

```
public class MyBean implements Serializable{
 private List<String> contacts;
   private Map<String,Object> changedValues;

    ... Getters & Setters
 }
```

On debugging, my Spring MVC controller I am hoping to get the list of only the changed contacts via the "changedValues" Hash Map. This is where the square brackets seem to break - 
The key that Spring Binding maps now looks like

```
contacts[0  12312312313
contacts[1  345354535
contacts[2  35534534
name Sam
```

This breaks my code as the second square brackets were not understood by Spring Data Binding.

Still exploring if I can make Spring understand this binding of mine.

Comment: What's the HTTP Content-Type header?

Comment: Content-Type on Http Request is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"

Comment: Is this consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE} helping?>

Comment: I'm not getting. Just break it what should be stored in contacts and changes values ?

Comment: No, change `@PostMapping("/saveMyPage")` to `@PostMapping("/saveMyPage", consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE} )`

Comment: Also, you can change your method to 
`public String saveMyPage(@RequestBody MyBean oBean)` if you don't need other parameters.

Comment: @RequestBody is failing with message - Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported. MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE still has the issue with ModelAttribute